# Is it possible to fill transparency with white in a texture in code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, transparency, fill

I have some textures containing some transparency parts (a donut, for example, which would show a transparent center). What I want to do is fill the middle of the donut (or anything else) with a plain white, in code (I don't want to have a double of all my assets that need this tweak in one part of my game).

Is there a way to do this? Or do I really have to have 2 of each of my assets?

Comment: Sure Texture2D has functionality to read and write pixels if you want to. And you could develop a simple flood fill. Whether that's a smart thing to do is another issue I guess.

Comment: why would it not be smart ? and how simple is it ?

Comment: I'd personally rather work with discrete assets and find a solution with those, rather than having to manipulate them on the fly. (Not to mention performance concerns, depending on the exact scenario). As for a flood fill: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to achieve. In case of donut: do you want only center of donut to be filled with white or every pixel that is transparent. Also, what is transparent? What about semitransparent pixels?

Comment: Say my donut is pink, and everything else is transparent (alpha 0). My texture is square-shaped, with a pink donut for example, and alpha in the middle. I'd want only the middle alpha part to be filled with white for example, because I want to place that asset on top of something else but not show it in the middle. I still want to be able to hide the alpha square around the texture. So I don't want to change all the transparency to white.

Comment: What is the REAL use case of it? Not hypothetical one with donuts. Quite possible, that you have chosen wrong direction of solving your problem. Description of real problem will help us understand it and advise with solution.

Comment: The user uses a webcam to take a picture. I save that picture as a texture and use it as a background. The user may then place textures in the picture, but some of these original pictures have transparent parts in them (much like a hole in a donut), which I want to replace for this case (when the background is a picture taken by the user, and not my own background that fits well with the transparency of those particular textures). So I'd want to fill those "donut holes" with white.

Comment: That does not make too much sense. When would your picture with transparent parts not fit well with the picture taken by the user?

Comment: Hm... I would say that filling is not what you want here. Create (by hands) a mask for each of your donut-like textures that you will draw below them to cover holes. Or create (again, by hands) second versions for each of your donut-like textures without holes.

Comment: Can't really elaborate that much more, it might not make sense but at least do you understand what I want to achieve ?

Comment: My guess is that if the donut does not fit well with the background picture he wants to remove the transparency to let the user know they are doing the puzzle wrong.

Comment: Anyway, it's not solvable without having some sort of second texture (some mask, or hole-cap, or second version of texture with holes covered). While it's possible to create them automatically, I would only recommend to go with automatic creation only if there are a lot of textures.

Comment: I gave it a thought: you can also use color information of transparent pixels to determine whether you want them to became opaque or not. In conjunction with proper shader it will solve your problem. But it's tricky. And I don't know for sure how it will work with texture compression. And... I wouldn't chose this way if I were to solve such a problem. But, still, it's an option :)

Comment: Alright, guess I'll have to make a second set. Thansk for your input, if you want to make that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Nah, I'm too lazy today for a good answer :) And the problem is quite interesting and deserves it. So, I'll limit myself with comments only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First it is possible to change a transparent texture to not-transparent, if it wasn't then graphic editors would be in trouble.*

### Solution 1 - Easy but takes repetitive editing by hand

The question you should be asking yourself is can you afford the transition at run time or would have two sets of textures be more efficient; from experience I find that the later tends to be more efficient.

### Solution 2 - Extremely hard

You will need a shader that supports transparency and that it marks the sections that have to be shaded white. That is, it keeps track of which area will be later filled with white. It is implied that since your "donut" is already transparent on some parts then it already uses that texture that has an alpha, but you will have to write your own shader mask and be able to distinguish which is okay to fill white and which is not (fun problem here). What you need to do is find the condition in which that alpha no longer needs to be alpha and has to be white. Once the condition is met you can change the alpha of via the Color's alpha property. The only way I see you able to do this is if there is a pattern to the objects, so that you can apply some mathematical model to them and use that to find which area gets filled. If the objects are very different then the make two sets of textures starts to look more appealing.

### Solution 3 - Medium with high re-use value

You could edit the textures to have two different colors, say pink and green. Green is the area that gets turned white and pink is always transparent. When green should not be white then it is transparent. You would have to edit your textures by hand as well.

Comment: I want to be able to fill in some transparent parts in my texture and replace them with some opaque white, but not the entire texture (not the alpha around the texture (square)). As in a square texture (say 250x250, containing a donut which has an opaque pink color, that is surrounded by transparency and has transparency in the middle(donut hole)). In that case I'd only want to fill the donut hole.

Comment: However, I believe it would be pretty complicated to do that in code since the textures may vary, so I think simplest way would be to create a second set of assets. Thanks !

Comment: @Bypp  I just thought of something, but it does require you to edit your texture to contain two extra colors.

Comment: Good idea, I'll have to test it out a bit more on my end and I'll get back to you ! Thanks !

Comment: Marked answer as accepted but everyone feel free to add more solutions or insight !